# morrisjs Area graph not showing the last xLabel

Tags: javascript, jquery, morris.js

Here is my code:

```
 var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
Morris.Area({
    element: 'chart_area',
    data: [{
        m: '2016-7',
        value: 19
    }, {
        m: '2016-6',
        value: 2
    }, {
        m: '2016-5',
        value: 3
    }],
    xkey: 'm',
    ykeys: ['value'],
    labels: ['Total Hit'],
    yLabelFormat: function(y) {
        return y != Math.round(y) ? '' : y;
    },
    xLabelFormat: function(x) {
        var month = months[x.getMonth()];
        return month;
    },
    dateFormat: function(x) {
        var month = months[new Date(x).getMonth()];
        return month;
    }
});
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m6m083da/2/) I have created. July xLabel is missing at the end.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `xLabels` option to your Morris initialization and set your interval to 'month', like so:

```
Morris.Area({
    ...
    xLabels: 'month',
    ...
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m6m083da/3/) showing it in action!

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help!